# JS DOM inside the for loop is not working with a string

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="drum">
 <li>A</li>
 <li>S</li>
 <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JS:

```
const Olist = document.querySelectorAll('.drum li');
  for(let i = 0; i < Olist.length; i++){
    Olist[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        console.log(`I was clicked ${Olist[i]}`);
    })
 }
```

My console.log() inside the loop returns the following: `I was clicked [object HTMLLIElement]` I don't understand why am I getting `[HTMLLIElement]` and not the actual `li`

*EDIT*
I am trying to understand why am I not getting the same result as when I simply `console.log(Olist[i])`. I have done this many times in the past, but I think there is something fundamental that I am missing here.

Comment: Try: `console.log(\`I was clicked ${Olist[i].innerHTML}\`);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that value because the `I was clicked ${Olist[i]}` is calling `.toString()` on the `HTMLLIElement` instance. If you want to see the HTML for the element, try calling `I was clicked ${Olist[i].outerHTML}`.

```js
const Olist = document.querySelectorAll('.drum li');


for (let i = 0; i < Olist.length; i++) {
  Olist[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(`I was clicked ${Olist[i].outerHTML}`);
    console.log(`Olist[i].toString() => ${Olist[i].toString()}`);
  })
}
```

```html
<ul class="drum">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you elaborate a little more on the `.toString()` part. I mean I am definitely not clear how this is happening, I feel like there is more to this? Any recommended reading maybe? Thanks much for your help!

Comment: @BradShaw When you concatenate an object, in this case `HTMLLIElement`, to a string, the object's `.toString()` method is called. All prototypes in JavaScript derive from the base Object prototype. The Object prototype defines a `toString()` method that your child prototypes can override. The `HTMLLIElement` prototype does not appear to override this. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString for more information.

Comment: @BradShaw Here's a fiddle for clarification, and some parallels to your question:

https://jsfiddle.net/gyavskdo/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution.

```js
// Convert a HTMLCollection to an array, then apply the following code for each item
// within the array.
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.drum li')).map(li => li.onclick = () => {
  const string = li.outerHTML;
  console.log(string + ' Was clicked');
});
```

```html
<ul class="drum">
 <li>A</li>
 <li>S</li>
 <li>D</li>
</ul>
```